# node-webkit in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, node-webkit

I wrote a simple native Node addon in c++ using Visual Studio, following [this tutorial](http://wiki.gpii.net/w/Building_node.js_Windows_C/C%2B%2B_Addons)

It needs to use Visual Studio so it can access the Windows API.

I need to build this for node-webkit.

How can I do this? What is vcbuild.bat doing?

Thanks!

Comment: I may have found a solution: Try to build the node native addon as you normally would for node-webkit (nw-gyp rebuild --target = 0.8.6) Then go into the generated solution file, and paste the code from the tutorial mentioned in the original question. Instead of giving the path to node.lib, give it the path to nw.lib (search for it). Then hit f7 to build, move the build addon.node to the right directory, and it worked for me.

Comment: also copy stdafx and other files it asks you for. You can get them from the directory you create after going through the first tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Build it normally with nw-gyp rebuild --target=0.8.6, then go into build and open the solution. Then follow the steps described in the tutorial, but replace the path to node.lib with the path to nw.lib. A few other files might need to be moved around too, but those are more straightforward.